# MiniProfiler page loading twice per request

Tags: asp.net, webforms, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

I've boiled this down to the smallest example:

### Test.aspx

(Code behind is empty)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="C3.Pages.Test" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="StackExchange.Profiling" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <%=MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes() %>
</body>
```

## Global.asax

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.IsLocal)
        {
            MiniProfiler.Start();
            var ignored = MiniProfiler.Settings.IgnoredPaths.ToList();
            ignored.Add("WebResource.axd");
            MiniProfiler.Settings.IgnoredPaths = ignored.ToArray();
        }
    }
    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        MiniProfiler.Stop();
    }
```

This produces the result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here?  I'm expecting only one to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, figured it out.  It was an old version of Adblock Plus that was for some reason requesting each page twice.

Running in Incognito mode stopped the issue happening.  Updating the Adblock Plus extension fixed the issue.